Minimizing a submodular function containing summation and production under partition matroid constraint
I'm having difficulty solving the following problem: We're given $n$ sets $X_1,\ldots, X_n$. Each set $X_i=\{(a_i,b_i)\}$ contains poly(n) many ordered pairs of non-negatives with $0\le a_i+b_i\le 1$. The question is to find a set $S\subset \bigcup_{i}X_i$ with $|S\cap X_i|\le 1$ for each $i$, such that the following function is minimized:
$$f(S)=\prod_{(a,b)\in S}a+\sum_{(a,b)\in S}b,$$
where $f(\emptyset):= 1$.
Let $(\mathcal{I}, \bigcup_iX_i)$ be a partition matroid where $\mathcal{I}=\{S'\subset \bigcup_iX_i: |S'\cap X_i|\le 1\}$. It's easy to see that $f:\mathcal{I} \to \mathbb{R}$ is submodular. So essentially, the problem specializes the minimization of a submodular function subject to a partition matroid constraint, which in general is hard (see this post). Is there a polynomial-time algorithm to minimize $f$? Or can the problem be proved NP-hard?
Some observations:

When $|X_i|=1$ for every $i$, the problem boils down to the classical submodular minimization, which is known to admitting a polynomial-time algorithm.
The maximization version with $|X_i|=1$ is addressed in this post, which discusses a polynomial-time algorithm. The algorithm depends on the fact that the extended $f$, defined over the hypercube $[0,1]^n$, is convex, so the extended $f$ is maximized over $[0,1]^n$ at some extreme point of the hypercube. However, I think this approach does not apply when attempting to minimize a convex function.

